# How can I create a distance limit where the player will stop slowly smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetectCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public Transform target;
    public bool turnOnOffPlayerAnimator = false;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 3;
    float startValue = 1;
    float endValue = 0;
    float valueToLerp = 0;

    private Animator playerAnimator;
    private bool entered = false;
    private bool prevFacing = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var currFacing = IsFacing(target);
        if (currFacing != prevFacing)
        {
            // here you switched from facing to not facing or vise verca.
            timeElapsed = 0;
        }
        prevFacing = currFacing;

        var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, target.position);

        if(distance <= 30)
        {
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", 0);
        }

        if (IsFacing(target))
        {
            if (entered && distance > 30)
            {
                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(startValue, endValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (valueToLerp < 0.9f)
            { 
                if (timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
                {
                    valueToLerp = Mathf.Lerp(endValue, startValue, timeElapsed / lerpDuration);
                    playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
                    timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
                }
                playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", valueToLerp);
            }
        }

        if(turnOnOffPlayerAnimator)
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            playerAnimator.enabled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        entered = true;

        Debug.Log("Entered !");
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        entered = false;

        Debug.Log("Exited !");
    }

    private bool IsFacing(Transform target)
    {
        Vector3 forward = player.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        Vector3 toTarget = target.position - player.position;
        return Vector3.Dot(forward, toTarget) > 0;
    }
}
```

The distance limit is working at this part :

```
var distance = Vector3.Distance(player.position, target.position);

        if(distance <= 30)
        {
            playerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", 0);
        }
```

but then the player just suddenly stop and it looks ugly.

and if I will copy the slow down to stop part to this part I'm afraid the player will slow down to stop but will get over the distance limit because he is not stopping at once but slowly.

and this slowly to stop is nice and looking good.

so I'm a bit stuck here with this logic part.

I thought maybe somehow to do that the distance limit the player will slow down smooth to stop depending on how much distance he is from the distance limit. so there should be some logic of how fast or slow the slow down will be if the player is closer or maybe more away from the distance limit.

I don't want the player to pass this distance and any other area/s beyond this distance that is bigger then 30 the player can move but at the distance limit he should not be able to pass it.

Comment: Do you want the player to die when they hit the distance limit or should the distance limit just be like a wall?

Comment: @Simonster to be like a wall but not like now when I'm setting the speed value of the "Forward" to 0 something else something more realistic maybe also to slow down to stop but depending on how much the player is close to the distance limit and then slow down slowly or faster to stop. but the idea is to make it like wall just not to stop it at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code to slow down the character:

```
float distance = player.position.x - target.position.x;
float threshold = 10

if (IsFacing(target) && distance < threshold)
{
    PlayerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", distance / theshold)
}
else
{
    PlayerAnimator.SetFloat("Forward", 1);
}
```

This makes it so the player can't go past the target on the x-axis and if it is close enough, it will slow down the closer it gets. It will only slow down if the player is facing the wall.

This is also assuming the normal speed you want is 1.

The `IsFacing` function is the `IsFacing` in your code.

You can also negate everything to make the player go on the opposite side of the wall.